# Remove Item from generic list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to remove an item from a generic list using RemoveAt.  The odd thing is while using the debugger I can see my item has been removed and yet when passing it to a view the item removed is showing up but the last item has been removed.

Code looks like this

```
public ActionResult(MyModel model, int[] removeitems)
{
 //model.ListItems has 10 items
 //Incoming removeitems has 0 as the first item to remove as a test
foreach(int item in removeitems)
{
 model.ListItems.RemoveAt(item);
}
 //by this time debugger shows that item 0 has in fact been removed and no longer exists in the list
 return View(model);
 //after the view is rendered it shows item 0 is still there but 10 has been removed
}
```

I understand that I can do it another way by copying the items into another list etc, but all tests show the above code does remove the first item and yet the view does not reflect this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your view code....I think, there is some evil part in view code....

Comment: Are you sure you do not want `.Remove()` which finds the element and removes it? Well finds the first matching element and removes it.

Comment: @Nomad101 I thanks I am aware of the Remove it is not what I want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you remove items the indexes change. For example after you remove the 0th item, the item which was the 1st item will now be the 0th. To prevent this remove items from the end towards the beginning:

```
foreach(int item in removeitems.OrderByDescending(n => n))
{
    model.ListItems.RemoveAt(item);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that it worked, out of interest does anyone know why the debugger and the tests do work and the View does not?

Comment: @AliK It depends on the test. It doesn't fail if `removeitems` contains only 1 item, or it is already sorted descending.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound quite silly, but is it possible that your result is being overwritten from somewhere else?

Comment: I did consider that and can be sure that is not the case as my view is very simple and just lists the items in the list.